# how to update state according to id?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

[image]

I have a touchableopacity on each card where I want to setstate of expand to true, but I want to do it according to the id, so that state of only one changes, any idea how to do it using map()?

My code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import {ROOT} from '../../../../ApiUrl';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
export default function VaccinationListScreen(props) {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState('');

  let id = props.route.params.id;
  const getData = () => {
  
    let url = `some url`;
    console.log('bbb');

    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res.data.content);
        setData(res.data.content);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
      
        <TouchableOpacity style={{padding: 10}} onPress={()=>setExpand(true)}>
          {data != undefined &&
            data != null &&
            data.map((item) => {
              return (
                <View
                  style={{
                    padding: 10,
                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                    elevation: 3,
                    margin: '2%',
                    borderRadius: 5,
                  }}
                  key={item.id}>
                  <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
                    <Text style={{color: 'grey', fontSize: 12}}>
                      {item.display_date}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <View>
                      <Image
                        source={require('../../assets/atbirth.jpg')}
                        style={{height: 40, width: 50}}
                        resizeMode="contain"
                      />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1}}>
                        <Text
                          key={item.id}
                          style={{
                            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                          }}>
                          {item.name}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: '30%'}}>
                        {item.vaccine_list.map((i) => {
                          return (
                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                              <Text
                                numberOfLines={1}
                                ellipsizeMode="tail"
                                style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontSize: 15}}>
                                {i.name},
                              </Text>
                            </View>
                          );
                        })}
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-end', marginTop: '1%'}}>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                      <Text
                        style={{
                          color: 'red',
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: 'bold',
                        }}>
                        {item.child_vacc_status.text}
                      </Text>
                      <Icon
                        name="chevron-up"
                        color="red"
                        size={12}
                        style={{marginTop: '1%', marginLeft: '1%'}}
                      />
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </View>
              );
            })}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Any suggestions would be great, do let mw know if anything else is required for better understanding

Comment: Please add your code. This link might be helpful ([mcve])

Comment: added code @Tim

Comment: Please also add a snapshot of how your received data looks like ;)

Comment: already added. I want to set the expand state to true and display some other data when true when expand is true, but I want to change it according to id.

Comment: It seems you render only a single `TouchableOpacity` around your entire list, or am I misunderstanding your structure? Generally if you want to toggle any single element you should store its id in `expand` (instead of a boolean), and simply check when rendering the array if any specific element's id matches, i.e. `element.id === expand`. When any new element is touched, pop its id in there, if the id is already there, set to `null` to collapse.

Comment: Yes, could you please write a snippet regarding the same? @DrewReese

Comment: Sure, I can try. Answered below and took a guess as to where a `TouchableOpacity` should go to wrap each element being mapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i review your code `<TouchableOpacity>` wraps all of your cards at once not on each card set. If you implement your code that way if it's not impossible it will be difficult for you to reference each cards id and set the state of expand to true according to cards id.

My suggestion is to include `<TouchableOpacity>` to `map()` function nest so that it will be easy to reference each cards function.

I reproduce this specific problem and implement a solution in which I was able to set the state of expand to true according to each cards id.

You may click the sandbox link to see a demonstration.

https://codesandbox.io/s/accordingtoid-4px1w

**Code in Sandbox:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View
} from "react-native";
// import axios from 'axios';
// import {ROOT} from '../../../../ApiUrl';
// import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";

export default function VaccinationListScreen(props) {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState({});
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  // let id = props.route.params.id;
  // const getData = () => {

  //   let url = `some url`;
  //   console.log('bbb');

  //   axios
  //     .get(url)
  //     .then(function (res) {
  //       console.log(res.data.content);
  //       setData(res.data.content);
  //     })
  //     .catch(function (err) {
  //       console.log(err);
  //     });
  // };
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   getData();
  // }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // In order to simulate and reproduce the problem
    // Assume that these are the data that you fetch from an API
    const dataContent = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "At Birth",
        display_date: "02 May - 08 May 16",
        vaccine_list: [
          { name: "BCG" },
          { name: "Hepatitis B" },
          { name: "OPV 0" }
        ],
        child_vacc_status: { text: "Missed" }
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "At 6 Weeks",
        display_date: "02 May - 08 May 16",
        vaccine_list: [
          { name: "IPV" },
          { name: "PCV" },
          { name: "Hepatitis b" },
          { name: "DTP" },
          { name: "HiB" },
          { name: "Rotavirus" }
        ],
        child_vacc_status: { text: "Missed" }
      }
    ];

    setData(dataContent);
  }, []);

  function handleOnPress(id) {
    setExpand((prev) => {
      let toggleId;
      if (prev[id]) {
        toggleId = { [id]: false };
      } else {
        toggleId = { [id]: true };
      }
      return { ...toggleId };
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(expand); // check console to see the value
  }, [expand]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      {data !== undefined &&
        data !== null &&
        data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={item.id}
              style={{
                padding: 10
              }}
              onPress={() => handleOnPress(item.id)}
            >
              <View
                style={{
                  padding: 10,
                  backgroundColor: expand[item.id] ? "lightgrey" : "#fff",
                  elevation: 3,
                  margin: "2%",
                  borderRadius: 5
                }}
              >
                <View style={{ alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
                  <Text style={{ color: "grey", fontSize: 12 }}>
                    {item.display_date}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                  <View>
                    <Image
                      // source={require('../../assets/atbirth.jpg')}
                      style={{ height: 40, width: 50 }}
                      resizeMode="contain"
                    />
                  </View>
                  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flex: 1 }}>
                      <Text
                        key={item.id}
                        style={{
                          fontFamily: "Roboto",
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: "bold"
                        }}
                      >
                        {item.name}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", width: "30%" }}>
                      {item.vaccine_list.map((item, i) => {
                        return (
                          <View key={i} style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                            <Text
                              numberOfLines={1}
                              ellipsizeMode="tail"
                              style={{ fontFamily: "Roboto", fontSize: 15 }}
                            >
                              {item.name},
                            </Text>
                          </View>
                        );
                      })}
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View style={{ alignItems: "flex-end", marginTop: "1%" }}>
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        color: "red",
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: "bold"
                      }}
                    >
                      {item.child_vacc_status.text}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        })}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested the code to work correctly, but you could try something similar. You could create a separate component for the items and set a status for each of them.

```
export default function VaccinationListScreen(props) {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  const VaccinationListItem = (item) => {
    const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ padding: 10 }} onPress={() => setExpand(true)}>
        <View
          style={{
            padding: 10,
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            elevation: 3,
            margin: "2%",
            borderRadius: 5,
          }}
          key={item.id}
        >
          <View style={{ alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
            <Text style={{ color: "grey", fontSize: 12 }}>
              {item.display_date}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <View>
              <Image
                source={require("../../assets/atbirth.jpg")}
                style={{ height: 40, width: 50 }}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flex: 1 }}>
                <Text
                  key={item.id}
                  style={{
                    fontFamily: "Roboto",
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                  }}
                >
                  {item.name}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", width: "30%" }}>
                {item.vaccine_list.map((i) => {
                  return (
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                      <Text
                        numberOfLines={1}
                        ellipsizeMode="tail"
                        style={{ fontFamily: "Roboto", fontSize: 15 }}
                      >
                        {i.name},
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  );
                })}
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={{ alignItems: "flex-end", marginTop: "1%" }}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: "red",
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                }}
              >
                {item.child_vacc_status.text}
              </Text>
              <Icon
                name="chevron-up"
                color="red"
                size={12}
                style={{ marginTop: "1%", marginLeft: "1%" }}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
        {data != undefined &&
          data != null &&
          data.map((item) => {
            VaccinationListItem(item);
          })}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution but I wouldn't define the `VaccinationListItem` component inline because it would be recreated every time the parent renders.

Comment: If you insert the component directly inside the state it will be recreated every time, but if you go to recall one that already exists inside the loop you could get some advantages.

Comment: I mean you should pull the definition of `VaccinationListItem` out of `VaccinationListScreen`. There is no reason to make it a closure. The javascript interpreter will always create the function again even if it doesn't use anything from the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you want to toggle any single element you should store its id in `expand` (instead of a boolean), and simply check when rendering the array if any specific element's id matches, i.e. `element.id === expand`. When any new element is touched, pop its id in there, if the id is already there, set to `null` to collapse.

```
export default function VaccinationListScreen(props) {
  const [expandId, setExpandId] = useState(null); // <-- stores null or id, initially null
  
  ...

  // Create curried handler to set/toggle expand id
  const expandHandler = (id) => () =>
    setExpandId((oldId) => (oldId === id ? null : id));

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
        {data &&
          data.map((item) => {
            return (
              <View
                ...
                key={item.id}
              >
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{ padding: 10 }}
                  onPress={expandHandler(item.id)} // <-- attach callback and pass id
                >
                  ...
                </TouchableOpacity>
                {item.id === expandId && ( // <-- check if id match expand id
                  <ExpandComponent />
                )}
              </View>
            );
          })}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```